# gulp-git reading response from status

Tags: node.js, git

think i'm not understanding how `gulp-git` works. I want to be able to check to see if there's uncommited changes and then run additional code depending on the result, however got some strange results, see the values within the comments:

```
let results = '';
git.status({ args: '--porcelain' }, (err, stdout) => {
    results = stdout;
    console.log(stdout.length); // 26
});
console.log(results.length);  // 0
```

How can I get the content from out of the `status` call back, return just returns a `Stream` is appears.

## Edit:

Based on Marco's answer I have done the following, however don't think I have understood the documentation correctly:

```
async getStatus() {
        const { stdout } = await git.status({ args: '--porcelain' });
        console.log(stdout);
    }
    pull() {
        process.chdir(`${this.localURL}/${this.code}`);
        this.getStatus().then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

The above outputs:

```
Socket {
  connecting: false,
  _hadError: false,
  _handle:
   Pipe {
     onread: [Function: onStreamRead],
     reading: true,
     [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular] },
  _parent: null,
  ...
undefined
[21:49:26] git status --porcelain
A  templates/dsdasdas.tpl
```

## Edit 2

Not quite got this still

```
getStatus() {
        util.promisify(git.status({ args: '--porcelain' }));
    }

    async pull() {
        process.chdir(`${this.localURL}/${this.code}`);

        let status = await this.getStatus().stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            return data;
        });
        console.log(`status: ${status}`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `results` in this line `console.log(results.length);  // 0` still refers to the first line `results`, which effectively has `length` equal to 0.
As you can now imagine, the problem is that the function you pass as the second parameter is a callback function.

I looked at the gulp-git source code and `git.status` uses `child_process.exec` function. Curious thing is that

> Unlike the exec(3) POSIX system call, child_process.exec() does not replace the existing process and uses a shell to execute the command.

So your `git status` command is actually executed in a different shell, this is the reason why `git.status` function returns immediately after been called, but passes the callback function you specify to the `child_process.exec` function.

You could promisify the whole call if you need to.

[Here](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-git/blob/master/lib/status.js) the source code of `git.status`.
[Here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) the documentation of `exec`.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, with "you could promisify the whole call" I meant that, instead of listening to the `data` event, you can wrap the `git.status` like this  `util.promisify(git.status)`. This automatically wrap the returned `exec` with a promise.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed I didn't quite have that part right

Comment: Yeah not got it, see my edit, won't work for me

Comment: More something like this `let promisifiedGitStatus = util.promisify(git.status)`